# how to code a graph with sgpanel in sas 9.2

Tags: graph, plot, sas

This works, but it uses the entire date range (starts) in each panel.
I want only Monday (panelby dayofweek) in the first panel, then Tuesday and so on.

```
proc sgpanel data=sortbyday nocycleattrs description="From harcpu";  
    where sysid in ("C");                                            
    panelby dayofweek / spacing=2 novarname columns=5;               
    format dayofweek wkday_name.;                                    
    vline startts / response=CPUAVR   /*Avg In/Ready   */            
        stat=mean                                                    
        markers                                                      
        markerattrs=(color=blue                                      
                     size=5px                                        
                     symbol=circlefilled);                           
    rowaxis max=12 grid;                                             
    colaxis grid;                                                    
    refline 6 9 /                                                    
        axis=y                                                       
        label="N * 2 = 6   N * 3 = 9"                                
        labelpos=auto                                                
        transparency=0.6                                             
        lineattrs=(color=red                                         
                   pattern=4                                         
                   thickness=5px);                                   
    inset day / position=topleft;                                    
    format startts datetime10.;
```

Comment: Please add some sample data to show your issue, or write your code to run off a SASHELP dataset (perhaps one of the stock datasets?)